# Extract text from txt list with command prompt Windows

Tags: command-line

I have a list in a txt like this

```
AAA 1234561
BBB12 66698732
CCCCC 5878471
DD131 262554158
```

and and I have a Directory like the below

```
DirectoryA/AAA
DirectoryA/BBB12
DirectoryA/CCCCC
DirectoryA/DD131
```

I want to create a txt file with a give name lets call it id.txt which contains the respective code for its folder

```
So the DirectoryA/AAA/id.txt contains 1234561
DirectoryA/BBB12/id.txt contains 66698732 and so on.
```

I tried to extract the line with /p but it copies the whole line not just the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%A in (x.txt) do echo %%B > DirectoryA\%%A\id.txt
```

---

#### Discussion:

You can get a lot of useful information by typing `FOR /?` into a Command Prompt.  In particular,

> `FOR /F  ["`*options*`"]  %`*variable*  `IN  (`*file-set*`)  DO` *command* `[`*command-parameters*`]`

reads the file or files specified between the parentheses (the *`file-set`*) and parses each line out into tokens.  `tokens=1-2` is the *`options`* string to say that you want the first and second words on each line.  `%%A` specifies that `%%A` is the variable that the first word will be read into; implicitly/automatically the second word goes into `%%B`.  Then the `echo` command gets executed with `%%A` and `%%B` set to the two words from the file.

**Note:** If you were typing this command directly into the Command Prompt, you would use `%A` and `%B`, but you have to use double percent signs when you do the same thing in a script (batch file).

Comment: Its working great can you please explain to me the tokens=1-2 and the whole thinking behind this command? thanks in advance

Comment: I hope I could rep you up Scott, thanks for the exlanation